# Display a ggvis plot in a shiny document

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

Is ggvis working with Shiny Documents yet?

In this example, ggplot is visible but ggvis is not

````
---
title: "testShiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

ggplot2

```{r, echo=FALSE}

require(ggplot2)

renderPlot({
  ggplot(women, aes(height, weight))+
    geom_point()+
    theme_bw()

  })

```

ggvis

```{r, echo=FALSE}

require(ggvis)

renderPlot({
  women %>%
    ggvis(x= ~height, y = ~weight) %>%
    layer_points()

  })

```
````

While searching  I came across bind_shiny, but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `bind_shiny` to assign an id to the visualisation. You then need to use `ggvisOutput` to create an element in the DOM to display the visualisation:

````
---
title: "testShiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}

require(ggvis)
require(knitr)
require(shiny)

ggvisOutput("p")

women %>%
  ggvis(x= ~height, y = ~weight) %>%
  layer_points()%>%
  bind_shiny("p")

```
````

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Do you know why `ggvisOutput("p")` has to come before the plot is called?

Comment: The order shouldnt matter I would think. I just tend to put `ui.R` objects beore `server.R`.